# Reducing space between annotation text and the line in a pin (PGFplots)

Tags: pgfplots

I need to reduce the distance between annotation text and the line which together form a conventional pin in pgfplots, see the figure below. Could anybody help me with this, please?

[image: Reducing distance]

MWE:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xlabel={$X$},
 ylabel={$Y$},
 ]
 \addplot [domain=0:10, ]{x};
 \node[coordinate, pin={[fill=white, pin distance = 5 mm]120:{A}}]
            at (axis cs:5,5) {};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Reduce pin's node inner sep: `pin={[fill=white, pin distance = 5 mm, inner sep=0pt]120:{A}}]`

Comment: cool, thanks! That answers my question. Could you post it as answer, @Ignasi , so that can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

All text in `TiKZ` (and `pgfplots`) is defined with `nodes` and all nodes have some `inner sep` between text border and node's border. You can see it in node `A` where node's border has been drawn.

This `inner sep` can be fixed to any value. `inner sep=0pt` eliminates all distance between node's border and text (nodes `B` and `C` in figure).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xlabel={$X$},
 ylabel={$Y$},
 ]
 \addplot [domain=0:10, ]{x};
 \node[coordinate, pin={[fill=white, pin distance = 5 mm, draw]120:{A}}]
            at (axis cs:4,4) {};
 \node[coordinate, pin={[fill=white, pin distance = 5 mm, draw, inner sep=0pt]120:{B}}]
            at (axis cs:5,5) {};
 \node[coordinate, pin={[fill=white, pin distance = 5 mm, inner sep=0pt]120:{C}}]
            at (axis cs:6,6) {};
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem has been solved by reducing the pin's node inner sep:

```
 pin={[fill=white, pin distance = 5 mm, inner sep=0pt]120:{A}}]
```

Many thanks for @Ignasi for his comment! Cheers!